# MySQL - how to get results back from a table, and the count of how many joined items there are in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
select display_order , section_name , solution_section_id from solution_sections order by display_order
```

It is very basic and gets the sections of a particular discussion. It works.

What I want to do is to also display the number of comments in each of the section.  So I want to do a join on the comments table and do a count on how many comments there are.

Here is the schema for the other tables:

```
mysql> describe suggested_solution_comments;
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| problem_id            | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suggested_solution_id | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commenter_id          | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment               | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| solution_part         | int(3)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                  | date           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| guid                  | varchar(50)    | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe solution_sections;
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| solution_section_id | int(10)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| display_order       | int(10)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| section_name        | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So it would have to be a join on solution_section_id and solution_part (those are the foreign keys even though they are named somewhat inconsistently) where problem_id = some id.

But how would I get the count of the number of returned comments in the suggested_solution_comments table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED with outer join:

```
select s.display_order, s.section_name, s.solution_section_id
      ,count(c.comment_id) AS comment_count
  from solution_sections s
  left outer join suggested_solution_comments c ON (c.solution_part = s.solution_section_id)
  group by s.display_order, s.section_name, s.solution_section_id
  order by display_order
```

Comment: that almost worked except it does not return the rows where the count is 0.  Any ideas how to fix that?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT solution_sections.display_order, solution_sections.section_name, solution_sections.solution_section_id, COUNT(suggested_solution_comments.comment_id) FROM solution_sections, suggested_solution_comments GROUP BY solution_sections.solution_section_id
```

Maybe try something like this? Its been awhile since i touched table joins, and your table naming looks pretty confusing to me.

Comment: that didn't quite work. It is giving the same count for all the sections. :)

Comment: I think you have to add a where clause as well. WHERE solution_sections.solution_section_id = suggested_solutions_comments.solution part

Comment: yes that is closer, but then it only returns the sections where there is more than 0 records and does not return items where there are 0 comments.

Comment: If there are no comments, there will not be any suggested_solution_id in your table. That is why it doesn't return any records without a comment. Like Glenn mentioned below, you would want to use outer joins in that case.